# Using the same switch for two devices of different signal voltage levels

Tags: switches, voltage-divider

When I press an ON-OFF type switch (SPST), I would like to have a corresponding HIGH or LOW registered on the inputs of both a 5V-level microcontroller as well as a 10V-level device, without damaging either one obviously.

How would I go about achieving this -- should I use a resistive divider?

Comment: Do they have a common ground?

Comment: @Trevor: Yes, common ground.

Comment: Trevor's answer is good and is what I would choose, provided you're ok with either using a normally-closed pushbutton or accepting an active-low signal on the destination devices. That said, your idea of using a voltage divider would be fine too - but beware of "sneak-path" powering the 5V MCU through the divider and switch when it's 5V supply is unpowered but the 10V is hot.

Comment: Out of curiosity what is the 10V device?

Comment: @pericynthion: Thank you for the suggestions. And sorry about this really late (and possibly boring) reply: It was one of the control inputs of a VFD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have common grounds you can use diodes like this.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGM6E2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: OK. I'm reading up now about diodes; I've only used them once before based on an example circuit. Would a diode like 1N4148 or 1N400x be appropriate here? Also, what values would you suggest for the resistors?

Comment: This sort of low speed signal logic application is not very sensitive to the choice of diode or resistor.  Either of those diodes would be fine. A 10k resistor is a safe bet.